# Short namespace acronym in ruby

Tags: ruby, namespaces, ironruby

I'm very new to ruby. I use IronRuby and my ruby code has long namespaces:

```
Company:: Division::Group::Product::Package.new
```

since I use this ns multiple times is there a way to create a shortcut? In c# I add a using clause so I'm not required to specify the full prefix.

Comment: You might want ot have a look at [make an alias for a module in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091740/is-it-possible-to-make-an-alias-for-a-module-in-ruby)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply assign it to another constant, like:

```
Package = Company::Division::Group::Product::Package
Package.new
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the "include" method, which is more Ruby-esk:

```
include Company::Division::Group::Product
Package.new
```

The difference between this and the current answer is that this one pulls in all constants under the namespace, where the current answer only pulls in that name.

Comment: This will not however avoid namespace conflicts. In other languages, often you can `import [Package] as [short_name]` I guess you could declare a class ivar to achieve the same result ? cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091740/is-it-possible-to-make-an-alias-for-a-module-in-ruby

Comment: True, this will not avoid naming conflicts, but that's due to how Ruby works.